# How to open the internal Docker URL using an external web page？

Tags: docker

I'm trying to reproduce the code from this github：[enter link description here](https://github.com/schrodinger/gpusimilarity). The purpose of this project is to use the GPU to perform some similarity search. Based on the instruction of the README file, I can now open the search server website inside the docker now. But I have tried many ways to try to open this server URL from an external browser, but all failed, can anyone help? Thanks!

Here is how I opened my server URL inside the Docker:

1. Download Docker Desktop.
2. Pull the images:

```
docker pull klorton/gpusimilarity:latest
```

3. From the docker directory(The docker file is inside the github), build:

```
docker build -t gpusim:internal .
```

4. Build a fingerprint file (Database), change PATH/TO/SMIGZ_DIR to your own path to the smi.gz file, change INPUT to your own smi.gz file.

```
docker run -v /PATH/TO/SMIGZ_DIR:/data -it gpusim python3 \
/gpusimilarity/bld/python/gpusim_createdb.py /data/INPUT.smi.gz \
/data/OUTPUT.fsim
```

5. Start a gpusimilarity server interactively, change /path/to/fsim/files to your own path to the fsim file.

```
docker run --net=host -v /path/to/fsim/files:/mnt/fsim -it \
klorton/gpusimilarity:latest python3 /gpusimilarity/bld/python/gpusim_server.py \
/mnt/fsim/OUTPUT.fsim --port 8080 --http_interface
```

6. The server will say "Ready for search" at this moment. Something like this:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4gCJ.png)

7.The server is running now. In the README file, the author said that we can just use the following link: http://localhost:8080 to open it. But I failed by doing this.

8. Then I tried to open the URL inside the Docker, install w3m first.

```
apt-get install -y w3m
```

9. Open the URL inside the Docker:

```
w3m http://localhost:8080
```

10. It shows like this:
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gKur.png)

Can someone tell me how to open this URL outside of Docker? Thanks a lot!

I have tried many of the methods available on Google, But most of them don't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. Just Downgrade docker and run the same process by linux.